# Python ignore punctuation and white space

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
string = "Python, program!"

result = []
for x in string:
    if x not in result:
        result.append(x)
print(result)
```

This program makes it so if a repeat letter is used twice in a string, it'll appear only once in the list. In this case, the string "Python, program!" will appear as

> ['P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', ',', ' ', 'p', 'r', 'g', 'a', 'm', '!']

My question is, how do I make it so the program ignores punctuation such as ". , ; ? ! -", and also white spaces? So the final output would look like this instead:

> ['P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', 'p', 'r', 'g', 'a', 'm']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the string (letter) is alphanumeric using [`str.isalnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) as an additional condition before appending the character to the list:

```
string = "Python, program!"

result = []
for x in string:
    if x.isalnum() and x not in result:
        result.append(x)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', 'p', 'r', 'g', 'a', 'm']
```

If you don't want numbers in your output, try [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) instead (returns `True` if the character is alphabetic).

Answer (score 1):

You can filler them out using the `string` module. This build in library contains several constants that refer to collections of characters in order, like letters and whitespace.

```py
import string

start = "Python, program!" #Can't name it string since that's the module's name
result = []
for x in start:
    if x not in result and (x in string.ascii_letters):
        result.append(x)

print(result)
```

Comment: What about numbers? They're dropped in this answer

Comment: Yes, numbers will be removed